# PHP 'opening Hours' - Time with custom field

Tags: php, datetime, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using this code to display a simple 'open' or 'closed' message. the code was taken from this question and adapted slightly - [Opening hours in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974888/opening-hours-in-php)

```
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); // timezone 

    $weekday = date(l); // today
    //print $weekday; // Debug
    //print date("H:i"); // debug

    // Set open and closing time for each day of the week
    if ($weekday == "Saturday") {
        $open_from = "10:00";
        $open_to = "14:00";
    }

   elseif ($weekday == "Sunday") {
        $open_from = "10:00";
        $open_to = "15:00";
    }

    else {
        $open_from = "10:00";
        $open_to = "17:00";
    }

    // now check if the current time is before or after opening hours
    if (date("H:i") < $open_from || date("H:i") > $open_to ) {
        echo '<div class="opening">Sorry , We Are Closed</div>';
    }

    // show open message
    else {
        echo '<div class="opening">We Are Open Now !</div>';
    }
?>
```

This Code works fine with the opening times entered manually , the problem i'm having is when i try and add a (ACF) custom field for the opening times , it stops functioning - As an Example for Sunday as below ?

```
elseif ($weekday == "Sunday") {
        $open_from = "<?php the_field('sunday_open','options'); ?>";
        $open_to = "<?php the_field('sunday_closed','options'); ?>";
    }
```

As soon as i enter the fields into the code , it will say 'Sorry , We Are Closed' , even though the opening times have been set in the ACF options time picker. When i change it back and enter it manually , like -

```
$open_from = "10:00";
$open_to = "15:00";
```

It works again and gives the message 'We Are Open Now !' correctly.

I ran this debug

```
<?php 

$time = get_field('sundays_open','options');

echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $time );
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

and it Returns this -

```
string '10:00' (length=5)
```

the output for the ACF time field is set to H:i

Can anyone point out what might be wrong here ?

Comment: Why you using php code with in quotes like : "<?php the_field('sunday_open','options'); ?>"

Comment: no error checking whatsoever and clearly a parse error. You want to be a developer, then use the tools that are at your disposal and don't code blindly

Comment: That's the thing , it didn't throw any errors , thanks all 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are placing PHP tags inside of PHP tags?

try,

```
elseif ($weekday == "Sunday") {
    $open_from = the_field('sunday_open','options');
    $open_to = the_field('sunday_closed','options');
}
```

Comment: *"try,"* - Not "try", but "use".

Comment: Thank you so much , i arrived at that after taking a break for a few hours ! LOL , Your answer is correct , it's all working perfectly now ... thanks again.